# genuine bulk email solution for support system

Tags: email

I have a support system for my clients where we send a ton's of reply to their support tickets, every day. We are using google suite as official email solution and many times we encounter the per day limit issue.

We have looked for our own SMTP server option but due to high manageability concern, we are looking for third party services.

I have checked Amazon SES, mailgun and mailchimp but I am still not conveyance for long term solution. The service provider must be "trusted" in terms of security and spamming and should not be blocked due to customer email policies.

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best solution that satisfies all your requirements would be sparkpost. It's the best cost effective and reliable third party solution according to my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, understand your concerns and the challenges with current market solutions. For tool like Support system, the emails delivery is very important.

Email senders like Sendgrid, Sparkpost, Amazon SES are well-known as bulk senders and suitable to handle bulk volume emails.Some of them have both front end and APIs available to support transactional emails. However as per my opinion Transactional emails require exclusivity.

We have seen cases, where companies lost their brand reputation due to failing in segregating infrastructure between Bulk and Transactional.

For Transactional email, you must give a thought on the reliable solutions like Aritic Mail or Postmark, as they are the pure transactional emailing system and designed exclusively for the same purpose. Which makes them more trustworthy brand for application developers.

Cheers
Rahul Singh